# OSIRIS-REx engines used during micro-maneuvers

Tags: engines, osiris-rex

During the Orbital-R phase, the ORX performs 12 micro-maneuvers (values obtained from NAIF's data file and SPICE library):

```
 #       UTC burn time        DV
 1  2019-11-03 14:09:50.146   54.5
 2  2019-11-10 14:20:00.258  280.8
 3  2019-11-17 14:20:04.164  277.3
 4  2019-11-24 14:19:40.597  185.4
 5  2019-12-01 14:14:56.756  223.9
 6  2019-12-08 14:10:32.991  316.4
 7  2019-12-15 14:15:09.062  258.2
 8  2019-12-18 14:09:36.028  118.0
 9  2019-12-25 14:10:21.431  297.2
10  2020-01-01 14:20:13.036  390.3
11  2020-01-05 14:14:27.238  198.7
12  2020-01-12 14:53:07.643  313.9
```

DV is expressed in micro-m/s. The NAIF's data files report the maneuvers as impulsive.

Does anyone know which engines are used for those micro-maneuvers?

I also know the s/c orientation during the burn, if it's of any help.

Comment: Cool data! are links to it secret or can they be shared? Is there any reason to withhold the orientation that you mention? It seems like that would be helpful.

Comment: @uhoh NAIF's data files are publicly available: https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/ORX/kernels/. I obtained those values from the file orx_191101_200114_191219_od207-N_v1.bsp located in the spk directory, but you need to wrote a program to do the calculations. It's not easy to post the ORX orientation (I can post the AR/DEC of the pointing direction of an axis, but I think that it would be useless); instead, an interactive 3D graph could be helpful (but it cannot be posted here): http://cristianopi.altervista.org/as/sonde_orx/11_orbr.html.

Comment: I love it! A few years ago I'd asked about adding WebGL to Space SE posts in [Is there a way to embed interactive planetary maps in stackexchange?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/880/12102) and since realized that OpenGL would be better. It would be fantastic if we could start adding 3D trajectories to posts. I've been putting off learning plotly but that works so nicely there, much better than matplotlib's `axes3D`.

Comment: I have a (possibly silly) question, are these micro-maneuvers primarily attitude adjustments, and the residual delta-vs just a side-effect? Or are the dv's desired?

Comment: @uhoh The big red diamond shows the place and the time of the maneuver. The graph clearly shows that the s/c is first rotated into the wanted attitude and *then* (after about 30 minutes) the engines are fired; hence those micro-maneuvers can't be a side-effect. After a few hours, the s/c is rotated back to the nadir-pointing attitude to use the instrument deck.